# SP Group not for Navigation audience but there it is in the Browse! Yargh!

Tags: navigation, audience-targeting

So Im modifying Navigation and decide to limit a particular item to an Audience. In the Audience field, I type "Approvers". It is returned as not found, what with the red squiggle and all. I use the Browse to locate the group. Clicking that little icon brings up the "Select Audiences" window. I flip the "Find" lookup to "SharePoint Groups" and type in "Approvers". There it is. I select it and click "Add" at the bottom, and click "OK". And back on the "Navigation Link" window, the "Audience" field shows the Red Squiggle of Death for the Audience.

**The "Approvers" group is right there, but showing as not found, when it was listed in the Browse! What gives?** Btw, this is for SP2010.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with target audience. To fix it, make sure the names of the SharePoint groups are Unique per site collection. Simply instead of using "Approvers" rename it to "Site_Name_Approvers". See here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spblog/archive/2012/02/01/sps2010-post-sp1-aug-cu-target-audience-cannot-resolve-sharepoint-group-name-when-multiple-groups-share-a-common-string.aspx

Comment: I am facing this issue in SP 2013 also. The SP group names are unique, still the audience targetting in Navigation does not resolve the groups !!